# Suggesting "safe enum" class for ISO C

Tags: c, enum, type-safety, macros, assertions

There are quite some questions and answers about how to make `enum` really type-safe and I didn't find a solution that ensures both type safety and valid values. So I took some ideas and extended it to my own generic solution, somehow resembling to *enum classes* used in some other languages.

My solution adds the overhead of a pointer dereference for getting the actual enum value, but I think this is a fair deal for situations where you would otherwise have to check for the valid range in a lot of places. Comparing values works naturally with the `==` operator because there is only one global constant instance of each enum value.

I'm posting it here for review and comments if you like -- please tell me if you spot a bug or any other weakness in my idea. Is there anything I overlooked?

The "implementation" is just a header file:

**csafenum.h**

```
#ifndef CSAFENUM_H
#define CSAFENUM_H

#ifndef __GNUC__
#define __attribute__(x)
#endif

#include <assert.h>

/* declare an enum type: CSAFENUM_DECL(TypeName); */
#define CSAFENUM_DECL(tname) struct tname##_struct; \
    typedef const struct tname##_struct * tname; \
    const char *tname##_name(tname e) __attribute__((nonnull(1))); \
    int tname##_val(tname e) __attribute__((nonnull(1)))

/* declare an enum member: CSE_DECL(TypeName, MemberName); */
#define CSE_DECL(tname, name) extern const struct tname##_struct * const name

/* define an enum type: CSAFENUM_DEF(TypeName); */
#define CSAFENUM_DEF(tname) struct tname##_struct { \
    int val; \
    const char * const name; \
}; \
const char *tname##_name(tname tname##_cannot_be_null) \
{ \
    assert(tname##_cannot_be_null); \
    return tname##_cannot_be_null->name; \
} \
int tname##_val(tname tname##_cannot_be_null) \
{ \
    assert(tname##_cannot_be_null); \
    return tname##_cannot_be_null->val; \
} \
struct tname##_struct

/* define an enum member: CSE_DEF(TypeName, MemberName, IntegerValue); */
#define CSE_DEF(tname, name, v) \
    static const struct tname##_struct name##_memb = { v, #name }; \
    const struct tname##_struct * const name = &name##_memb

#endif
```

---

### Example usage:

**fruit.h**

```
#ifndef FRUIT_H
#define FRUIT_H

#include <csafenum.h>

CSAFENUM_DECL(Fruit);

CSE_DECL(Fruit, Apple);
CSE_DECL(Fruit, Banana);
CSE_DECL(Fruit, Pear);
CSE_DECL(Fruit, Strawberry);

#endif
```

**fruit.c**

```
#include "fruit.h"

CSAFENUM_DEF(Fruit);

CSE_DEF(Fruit, Apple, 0);
CSE_DEF(Fruit, Banana, 1);
CSE_DEF(Fruit, Pear, 2);
CSE_DEF(Fruit, Strawberry, 3);
```

**main program**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "fruit.h"

int main()
{
    Fruit a, b, c, d;

    a = Apple;
    b = Banana;

    printf("a = %s (%d)\n", Fruit_name(a), Fruit_val(a));
    printf("b = %s (%d)\n", Fruit_name(b), Fruit_val(b));

    c = Apple;

    if (c == a) puts("c == a");
    if (c == b) puts("c == b");

    d = 0;

    printf("d = %s (%d)\n", Fruit_name(d), Fruit_val(d));

    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

> a = Apple (0)
>   b = Banana (1)
>   c == a
>   example: fruit.c:3: Fruit_name: Assertion `Fruit_cannot_be_null' failed.
>   zsh: abort      ./example/example

As pointed out by [DarkDust](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/51800/darkdust), this does not work in `switch` blocks -- pointers aren't allowed to switch on. After thinking about this issue for a while, I get the feeling better not to try solving this, because it would either weaken or overcomplicate (or both) the whole thing.

The whole code is on [GitHub](https://github.com/Zirias/csafenum).

Comment: I found this and your SO answer ( http://stackoverflow.com/a/31165425/20371 ) both via Google and I was about to write something snarky about how this was copied from that, but then saw it's the same guy! Hah.

Answer (score 2):

Another problem with making the enum values pointers, is that it changes the in-memory representation of an enum. There are many situations where it's necessary for the enum to be an int (such as reading/writing structs to/from files).

If you need type-checked enums, it is better to use C++.